# Disable Submit Button and Launch Alert Unless Checkbox is selected

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

There are quite a few other questions on here that tell you how to disable the submit unless a checkbox is selected. I can easily achieve that.

The issue that I am having is with firing an alert box when the submit is clicked while the checkbox is unchecked. I want to tell the user "You must select an option first!" before submitting.

Here's one of the many versions I have tried. (this is simplified down)Thanks Guys!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

        $("form").submit(function(e){
        if($("#terms").not(':checked')){
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('Please check the first checkbox!');
        } 
                         return true;
    }
});



});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="http://google.com">
    <input type="checkbox" name="cb1" id="terms" value="a" /> A<br />

    <!-- disable our submit button by default -->
    <input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $("form").submit(function (e)
    {
        if ($("#terms:not(:checked)").length > 0)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('Please check the first checkbox!');
            return false;
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you a ton. Can you give me any brief explanation on using return false?

Comment: the second to last closing statement just needs a });

Comment: @user1104850 Sure. each Js function before posting back to server can be blocked if you do " return false" from its onclick method. ( or earlier stage of click). once you return false - it wont continue to the server side. remember that a function can only use only 1 return statement. ie : return 1; return 2;   - will always return 1.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 

        $("form").submit(function(e){ 
        if(!$("#terms").is(':checked')){ 
            e.preventDefault(); 
            alert('Please check the first checkbox!'); 
        }  
                         return true; 
    } 
);
```